# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable, despite being a list

Tags: python, search, computer-science, linear-search

I was coding a linear search in Python, but it seems I got a syntax problem.

I have a function which receives an array, and inside the function I got the lenght of that array throught len function. The problem is that, despite being passing an array to the function it raises an error 'int' object is not callable.

I would highly appreciate it someone could tell me what did I did wrong and why this is happening.

I left my code below.

```
from random import *

def linear_search(array, value):
    for i in range(len(array)): #line where the program raises the error
        if array[i] == value:
            i = len(array)
            return 0
    return 1

n = []
len = 25

for i in range(len):
    n.append(randint(0,100))

value = n[randint(0,24)]

result = linear_search(n, value) #calling to the function
```

Comment: `len = 25` you've assigned `len` the value of `25`, overwriting the built-in `len()` method and now python sees `for i in range(25(array)):`

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem, thxs

Comment: "but it seems I got a syntax problem" – I am intrigued: why would you think you got a syntax problem if you get no syntax error? If you had a syntax problem, Python would not even be able to parse your code, i.e. it would fail long before it even gets a chance to run it. The fact that you get a runtime error *clearly* shows that there is no syntax problem. It is a semantic problem. The name of the exception is `TypeError`, so even if I knew nothing about Python, that would indicate to me that the error is … uhm … a type error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the working code:

from random import *

```
def linear_search(array, value):
    for i in range(len(array)):  # line where the program raises the error
        if array[i] == value:
            i = len(array)
            return 0
    return 1


n = []
length = 25 #renamed this from len to length

for i in range(length):  #renamed this from len to length
    n.append(randint(0, 100))

value = n[randint(0, 24)]

result = linear_search(n, value)
```

the code you have given had the issue that when defining this for loop:

```
for i in range(len):  
        n.append(randint(0, 100))
```

**Issue**: The var `len` is the build-in function `len()` and not an integer